# FixedLenSequenceFeature unexpected behaviour

Tags: python, tensorflow, protocol-buffers

Tried to better understand the most popular sequential TFRecord tutorial:
http://www.wildml.com/2016/08/rnns-in-tensorflow-a-practical-guide-and-undocumented-features/

Where this came up in the serialization part:

```
fl_tokens = ex.feature_lists.feature_list["tokens"]
fl_labels = ex.feature_lists.feature_list["labels"]

for token, label in zip(sequence, labels):
  fl_tokens.feature.add().int64_list.value.append(token)
  fl_labels.feature.add().int64_list.value.append(label)

return ex
```

why we couldn't use this?

```
ex.feature_lists.feature_list["tokens"].int64_list.value.extend(sequence)
ex.feature_lists.feature_list["tokens"].int64_list.value.extend(labels)
```

Using the latter method will result in the following error (which I hardly understand)

```
InvalidArgumentError: Name: , Key: tokens, Index: 0.  
Number of int64 values != expected.  values size: 22 but output shape: []
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming `ex` is a `tf.SequenceExample`, I get a different error from you:

```
>>> ex = tf.SequenceExample()
>>> sequence = [1, 2, 3]
>>> ex.feature_lists.feature_list["tokens"].int64_list.value.extend(sequence)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
AttributeError: 'FeatureList' object has no attribute 'int64_list'
```

However, the following code at least appears to be syntactically correct, so I assume you mean the following:

```
>>> ex.feature_lists.feature_list["tokens"].feature.add().int64_list.value.extend(sequence)
```

Why does creating the example this way yield an error? The short answer is that the data is subtly different. When you do the following, you are creating an example whose `token` feature list has 22 scalar values:

```
for token, label in zip(sequence, labels):
  fl_tokens.feature.add().int64_list.value.append(token)
```

Notice that you're calling `feature.add()` once for each element of `sequence`. By contrast, in the `extend()`-based version you're creating an example whose `token` feature list is a single value, which is a vector of 22 elements.

While these might be mathematically equivalent, TensorFlow's [`tf.parse_single_sequence_example()`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/parse_single_sequence_example) function expects you to pass explicit shapes when you define the various features in the `sequence_features` argument, and will raise the error you are seeing if they do not match.

Comment: however with python's native list, the two operations would be identical.